# Change log level of project with single call?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have configured the log level in properties to DEBUG and works fine, but i want to change the log level of whole project if some event occurs.Apparently my project has many classes and they use the logging like below

```
   private static final Logger log  = Logger.getLogger(CommandOperations.class);
```

I am able to change the log level individually for each class by calling    `log.setLevel(Level.INFO)` but I rather want project wide change. How to do it?

Comment: can u put the config part where you have configured it as DEBUG

Comment: Try `Logger.getLogger("com.xx").setLevel(..);` where `com.xx` is the package prefix to all your classes. Do not set levels for individual classes.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but it is working for specific package, Can we do it  recursively.like com.app.* applies to all sub packages , i tried that but didn't work out

Comment: Does it work for all subpackages when you give just "com.app" ?

Comment: Yeah , i got that right, if you answer it i would accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Logger.getLogger("com.xx").setLevel(..);` where `com.xx` is the package prefix to all your classes. Do not set levels for individual classes.

When you give `com.xx` it will be applicable to all subpackages also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using?

```
LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel((Level)Level.DEBUG);
```